# app_offline.htm not working for rewritten URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have a Rewrite rule for a specific page, to make it more SEO friendly.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Friendly Threads">
            <match url="Topic/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[^[#\?]*\??(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="thread_messages.asp?ThreadID={R:1}&amp;PageNumber={R:2}&amp;{R:3}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But whenever I drop an `app_offline.htm` file in the root, the site will go to the `app_offline.htm` page for all URLs except for those matching the above match.

Is this expected, or have I possibly got something misconfigured somewhere?

If it makes any difference, this is a classic ASP site running under IIS 8 (Windows 2012).

(And yes, I know this is like putting a 90 year old behind the wheel of a Lamborghini.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `app_offline.htm` only works for ASP.NET. As the rewrite result is classic ASP, the page is handled by another IIS module, so it won't care about app_offline.htm existence.

In another saying, you have done nothing wrong, but classic ASP does not support `app_offline.htm`.